# django-rest-framwork how can i return the {[data1,data2]} instead of [data1,data2]

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i use django rest framework in my django backend app.

**a Circle is just like a Group.**

**i got following returns:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Administrator",
        "avatar": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/circle_avatars/python_gnSSWSO.pbm",
        "desc": "the group of administrators",
        "image": null,
        "created_date": "2015-07-31T03:24:21.116000Z"
    },
    {
        "name": "Developer",
        "avatar": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/circle_avatars/python_84E7KLC.ppm",
        "desc": "the group of developers",
        "image": null,
        "created_date": "2015-07-31T03:17:59.343000Z"
    }
]
```

**but it should be like this:**

```
{   
    circles:[
        {
            "name": "Administrator",
            "avatar": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/circle_avatars/python_gnSSWSO.pbm",
            "desc": "the group of administrators",
            "image": null,
            "created_date": "2015-07-31T03:24:21.116000Z"
        },
        {
            "name": "Developer",
            "avatar": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/circle_avatars/python_84E7KLC.ppm",
            "desc": "the group of developers",
            "image": null,
            "created_date": "2015-07-31T03:17:59.343000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

**the serializer:**

```
class CircleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Circle
        fields = ('name', 'avatar', 'desc', 'image', 'created_date')
        read_only_fields = ('created_date',)
```

**the CircleViewSet:**

```
class CircleViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Circle.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CircleSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

**And the Model:**

```
class Circle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True, db_index=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    avatar = models.ImageField(_('Avatar'), upload_to='circle_avatars')
    desc = models.TextField(_('Description'), max_length=560)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='circle_images', blank=True)

    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('C', _("Common")),
        ('B', _("Buddhism")),
    )
    category = models.CharField(_('Category'), choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='C', max_length=2, db_index=True)

    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)
```

Anyone has an idea?Thanks for any answer.

Comment: wrapping up with `{"circles": <your list>}` didn't work?

Comment: @ozgur Sorry for the Delay in My Reply,so i need Nested relationships?

Comment: where is your view code? how are you calling the serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by overriding the `to_representation()` method of the serializer.

As per DRF docs on [overriding serialization behaviour:](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior)

> If you need to alter the serialization, deserialization or validation
>   of a serializer class you can do so by overriding the
>   `.to_representation()` or `.to_internal_value()` methods.

You can do something like:

```
class CircleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Circle
        fields = ('name', 'avatar', 'desc', 'image', 'created_date')
        read_only_fields = ('created_date',)

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        # call the super() to get the default serialized data
        serialized_data = super(CircleSerializer, self).to_representation(obj) 
        custom_representation = {'circles': serialized_data} # insert the above response in a dictionary
        return custom_representation
```

Doing this will return something like:

```
{   
    circles:[
        {
            "name": "Administrator",
            "avatar": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/circle_avatars/python_gnSSWSO.pbm",
            "desc": "the group of administrators",
            "image": null,
            "created_date": "2015-07-31T03:24:21.116000Z"
        },
        {
            "name": "Developer",
            "avatar": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/circle_avatars/python_84E7KLC.ppm",
            "desc": "the group of developers",
            "image": null,
            "created_date": "2015-07-31T03:17:59.343000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```